# Regression with review scores containing excess zeroes

Tags: regression, bias, skewness, zero-inflation, noise

Here is an imaginary problem, representing something I am dealing with right now.

We have a set of movies with averages scores ranging from 0 to 10, such that the target is a continuous variable. By default all movies were given a score of 0. Over time some of the movies have been given a score, while others have yet to receive one.

The distribution might look like so:

[image]

Clearly there is some movies, that still need a 'true' score, and we want to predict that score, given the actually scored ones. **However**, we have no way to separate 0 target samples that were defaulted to 0, from those that have actually been scored a 0.

As such, by training a regressor on the full data set, would incorrectly result in a skew towards 0 scores. But fitting a regressor on only non-zero targets, would likewise skew the regressor towards non-zero scores.

I can think of two approaches to deal with this problem:

- Filter out 0 defaulted movies by first classifying 'scored' / 'not scored', hopefully separating default 0's from scored 0's and then fitting a regressor on the 'scored' classified samples only.
- Ignoring 0 scores all together when fitting the regressor, hoping the model extends nicely to 0 scores.

However I do not feel confident in either. What I think I am looking for, is a regressor that can deal with 0 values explicitly, so that a bias can be added towards the true distribution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a third, superior approach: [zero-inflated models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model). These are designed to account for cases such as yours, where there is an 'excess' of zeroes in the data. It is a type of mixture model commonly used with count data (specifically, this is usually a zero inflated Poisson regression).

It consists of two parts: one models the probability of getting a zero vs nonzero value (this binary part can be done with a logistic) and the other models the data in a non-binary manner (a variety of distributions may be appropriate here, including the Poisson). Zeroes can still be generated through the second portion of the model, but the *additional* zeroes that cause the large spike in your histogram will be accounted for by the first portion.